# Class 'SpatialPolygons' has no 'names' slot

Tags: r

I was trying to change the that the counties are correctly named, i.e., `alcona`, not `michigan,alcona` using the following code.

```
michigan.map <- map("county", 'michigan',plot=FALSE, fill = TRUE)
michigan.map$names
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(michigan.map$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
michigan.sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(michigan.map, IDs = IDs,
                            proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
plot(michigan.sp)
names(michigan.sp)
names(michigan.sp) <- sapply(strsplit(names(michigan.sp), ","), function(x) x[2])
```

It gives me:

> "Error in names(michigan.sp) <- sapply(strsplit(names(michigan.sp), ","),  : 
>     class 'SpatialPolygons' has no 'names' slot".

I'm not sure why because it has names slot.

Also as a side question, what does the IDs line do in the code?

Comment: Replace your first `IDs` line with this and see if that helps you grok what's going on: `IDs <- sapply(strsplit(michigan.map$names, ":"), function(x) gsub("michigan,", "", x[1]))`

Answer (score 1):

My comment shows how to fix what you're doing, but why not go further and use more modern/accurate county boundaries?

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(tigris) #devtools::install_github("walkerke/tigris")

mi <- counties("michigan", detailed=FALSE)
head(mi@data)
##     STATEFP COUNTYFP COUNTYNS       AFFGEOID GEOID         NAME LSAD      ALAND     AWATER
## 141      26      041 01622963 0500000US26041 26041        Delta   06 3033127269 2124385360
## 142      26      047 01622966 0500000US26047 26047        Emmet   06 1210886745 1073476051
## 143      26      097 01622991 0500000US26097 26097     Mackinac   06 2646869250 2793795315
## 144      26      141 01623013 0500000US26141 26141 Presque Isle   06 1706067776 4957327559
## 145      26      153 01623017 0500000US26153 26153  Schoolcraft   06 3033812509 1845664188
## 146      26      163 01623022 0500000US26163 26163        Wayne   06 1585109570  157120883

plot(mi)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
michigan.map <- map("county", 'michigan',plot=FALSE, fill = TRUE)
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(michigan.map$names, ","), function(x) x[2])
michigan.sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(michigan.map, IDs = IDs,
                                   proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
names(michigan.sp)
```

I think this code does what you want... it doesn't exactly answer your question. There must be a way to set the ID's of sp objects after creation, names<- is not it, however.

Answer (score 0):

`str(michigan.sp)` is your friend here; scroll through the results and you will see that there is, indeed, no slot `names`. Far easier and clearer, at least to me, is to make the change to `michigan.map`

```
michigan.map$names <- gsub('michigan,' ,'', michigan.map$names)
michigan.map$names
 [1] "alcona"         "alger"          "allegan"        "alpena"         "antrim"        
 [6] "arenac"         "baraga"         "barry"          "bay"            "benzie"        
[11] "berrien"        "branch"         "calhoun"        "cass"           "charlevoi"     
[16] "cheboygan"      "chippewa"       "clare"          "clinton"        "crawford"      
[21] "delta"          "dickinson"      "eaton"          "emmet"          "genesee"       
[26] "gladwin"        "gogebic"        "grand traverse" "gratiot"        "hillsdale"     
[31] "houghton"       "huron"          "ingham"         "ionia"          "iosco"         
[36] "iron"           "isabella"       "jackson"        "kalamazoo"      "kalkaska"      
[41] "kent"           "keweenaw"       "lake"           "lapeer"         "leelanau"      
[46] "lenawee"        "livingston"     "luce"           "mackinac"       "macomb"        
[51] "manistee"       "marquette"      "mason"          "mecosta"        "menominee"     
[56] "midland"        "missaukee"      "monroe"         "montcalm"       "montmorency"   
[61] "muskegon"       "newaygo"        "oakland"        "oceana"         "ogemaw"        
[66] "ontonagon"      "osceola"        "oscoda"         "otsego"         "ottawa"        
[71] "presque isle"   "roscommon"      "saginaw"        "st clair"       "st joseph"     
[76] "sanilac"        "schoolcraft"    "shiawassee"     "tuscola"        "van buren"     
[81] "washtenaw"      "wayne"          "weford"
```